# Problem using libtorch and pytorch at same time: Key already registered with the same priority: C10

Tags: python, visual-c++, pytorch, libtorch

I'm currently trying to implement a python torch model into a C++ application in VS22. Now the problem is that the C++ part uses libtorch and part of the python code uses pytorch.

Libtorch version: libtorch_win_shared_with_deps-1.13.1+cpu

Pytorch version: 1.13.1

Now when the python code imports torch I get the following error message:
"Key already registered with the same priority: C10"

Here is a simple example with pybind11 that causes this error:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <torch\torch.h>

int main()
{
  
  pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{};

  pybind11::module_ test = pybind11::module_::import("torch")

}
```

If I only use libtorch or pytorch everthing works fine, so my guess is that the same dll is loaded twice but I don't know how to prevent it. Also, I prefer to avoid using CMake at the moment if possible due to the size of the C++ application.